# TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index' python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I want to compute Compound monthly stock returns over 12 months to obtain annual returns.

Here is what I have done, but I am getting an error massage

```
Month_Return = pd.read_csv("Monthly Stock Return.csv") 
Month_Return.set_index('gvkey', inplace=True,drop = False)
Month_Return['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(Month_Return['Date'], format='%Y%M%d')
Month_Return['Date'] = Month_Return['Date'].dt.date




gvkey  issue   datadate    ticker  Company_name  Price_Close_Monthly    Stock Exchange  gsector

1003    1     2003-01-31    ANTQ    A.A             0.0400                  19.0        25.0
1003    1     2004-01-31    ANTQ    A.A.            0.0400                  19.0        25.0
1003    1     2004-01-29    ANTQ    A.A.            0.0400                  19.0        25.0
1003    1     2004-01-31    ANTQ    A.B             0.0400                  19.0        25.0
1003    1     2004-01-30    ANTQ    A.C             0.0001                  19.0        25.0
```

Then I retrieved the colunm I need to calculate the monthly return

```
Month_Return_annual.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
Month_Return_annual.index

 Date      Price_Close_Monthly  
2003-01-31  0.0400
2004-01-31  0.0400
2004-01-29  0.0400
2004-01-31  0.0400
2004-01-30  0.0001
2017-01-30  3.7600


results_storage['month'] = Month_Return_annual.index.month
results_storage['year'] = Month_Return_annual.index.year

Traceback:
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-855-f1ce19fc30ac> in <module>
  ----> 1 results_storage['month'] = Month_Return_annual.index.month
  2 results_storage['year'] = Month_Return_annual.index.year

 AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'month'
```

I understand that this error is coming from the .month method, But is there another way to achieve this..?

I fixed the first error using this

```
Month_Return_annual.index = pd.to_datetime( Month_Return_annual.index, 
                                     errors='coerce')
```

I also got another error massage when I tried calculating the monthly return

```
results_storage['month'] = Month_Return_annual.index.month
results_storage.head()

 Date       Price_Close_Monthly     year    month
 2003-01-31     0.0400              2003    1
 2004-01-31     0.0400              2004    1
 2004-01-29     0.0400              2004    1
 2004-01-31     0.0400              2004    1
 2004-01-30     0.0001              2004    1

df_Month_Return_annual = results_storage[['Price_Close_Monthly']].
                                   resample('M').ffill().pct_change()

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but 
got an instance of 'Index'
```

Comment: You need to use ` Month_Return_annual.index  = pd.to_datetime( Month_Return_annual.index)` to create a DateTimeIndex.  Then you can use ' Month_Return_annual.index.month`.

Comment: @ScottBoston  i got this error (TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index') when I tried using the pt_change() on the target column